# how to write Bash script for getting Public ip address in a way that when one command failed then it have to execute another command

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

i want to write a bash script in a way that if one command gets failed then it will have to execute another command.
For example:-
"curl www.ifconfig.me" if this command gets failed then another command "curl http://icanhazip.com" to get execute and should show the output.

Comment: You can get the result of the previous command with `[[ "$?" != 0 ]]` and execute the second curl.

Comment: What does failure mean with regards to curl? Getting a http response status that's anything but 200?

Comment: @Shawn yes regards to curl...  because sometimes happens one website may be in under maintainance so that we can get ip address using another website

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the HTTP code, try this:

```sh
$ RETURN_STRING=$(curl --silent --url "www.ifconfig.me" --write-out "\nHTTP_CODE:%{http_code}:" | tr "\n" " ")
$ echo $RETURN_STRING 
123.012.234.201 HTTP_CODE:200:
```

Then:

```sh
IP="${RETURN_STRING%% *}"
$ echo $IP
123.012.234.201
$ HTTP_CODE="${RETURN_STRING##*HTTP_CODE:}"
$ HTTP_CODE="${HTTP_CODE%%:*}"
$ echo $HTTP_CODE 
200
```

After that, you could check the HTTP_CODE value.

2.. => It's Ok